# Chaincode setup Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to setup Hyperledger Fabric chaincode development setup in my MAC machine. I already have the development environment setup, but my end goal is to just develop a blockchain application on top of Hyperledger Fabric. So I am moving towards the docker chaincode developement and test environment. I'm following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md#Option-3-Docker-Toolbox) (following the Option 2). The `docker-compose up` command is throwing the following error :

```
himanshus-mbp:fabric himanshutyagi$ docker-compose up
Recreating fabric_membersrvc_1
Creating fabric_vp_1

ERROR: for vp  driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint fabric_vp_1 (98887f3aa674ed269b3bf9cae87f28d7686920343a9cb2aac5f2715b1a945da8): Error starting userland proxy: write /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:5000:tcp:172.17.0.2:5000/ctl: errno 526
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

There is nothing related to this on the github issues. Can anyone explain what might be going wrong ?

Comment: hey, i got it working.

Comment: could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Similar to: https://forums.docker.com/t/networking-issues-in-beta8-errno-526/9770 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what process is running at port 5000 then try with `sudo lsof -i tcp:5000` then note the process id and run `sudo kill -15 <PROCESS_ID_HERE>`. After that retry running docker commad

Answer (score 0):

The port is probably already in use by another process. Has it already been started or is another program using the port.  Use `lsof` to help find the process.